# What is the complete process and purpose of a block validation using merkle trees?

Tags: merkle-tree

I need the whole details please. Like does that happen only in the current block? Or at past blocks do? And how exactly does this happen? Do full nodes send the proper hashes and then a local lightweight node calculates them until it reaches the merkle root?

An example with a step-by-step process explanation would be ideal. I need all the techincal details described as simple as possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does an SPV wallet use the headers that it downloads?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38418/how-does-an-spv-wallet-use-the-headers-that-it-downloads)

Comment: Related: [How do SPV wallets learn about incoming transactions?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11054/how-do-spv-simple-payment-verification-wallets-learn-about-incoming-transactio)

Comment: "does that happen only in the current block? Or at past blocks do?" none of your links answer this. they also don't describe the whole process in details.

Comment: Which "process" are you referring to? Are you asking how do full nodes validate the merkle root? Or are you asking how the merkle root is useful to SPV wallets?

Comment: @AndrewChow Both. Not the maths. The purpose and the process. Does this happen to past blocks or to the next block to be added on the chain?